# form送信ボタン押しても現在の表示がキープできるようにしたい。

Tags: php, jquery, html5

formで送信ボタン押して、input要素３項目打ち込まなければエラー表示がでて、全項目打ち込んだら次のページにリンクするようにしたいのですが、３項目打ち込まずにsubmitした時ページの先頭に戻るのを避けたかったのでjqueryで記述したら表示はキープされるようになったのですが、エラー表示に対応したPHP側が反応しなくなりました。どうしても原因がわからなく解決方法を教えていただきたいです。

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!empty($_POST)) {
  if ($_POST['name'] === '') {
    $error['name'] = 'blank';
  }

  if ($_POST['email'] === '') {
    $error['email'] = 'blank';
  }

  if ($_POST['message'] === '') {
    $error['message'] = 'blank';
  }
  
  if (empty($error)) {
    $_SESSION['join'] = $_POST;
    header('location: confirm.php');
    exit();
  }
}

$position = 0;
if (isset($_REQUEST['position']) === true) {
  $position = $_REQUEST['position'];
}
?>

      <form id="form" action="" method="POST">
        <div class="form-content mt-5">
          <div class="form-left ">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="名前"
              value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['name'], ENT_QUOTES)?>">
              <?php if ($error['name'] === 'blank') :?>
              <p class="text-danger">* 名前を入力してください</p>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group mt-5">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="メールアドレス"
              value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['email'], ENT_QUOTES)?>">
            <?php if ($error['email'] === 'blank') :?>
              <p class="text-danger">* メールアドレスを入力して下さい</p>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-right">
            <div class="form-group">
              <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="お問い合わせ"
               rows="10"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['message'], ENT_QUOTES)?></textarea>
            <?php if ($error['message'] === 'blank') :?>
              <p class="text-danger">* 本文を入力して下さい</p>
              <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input name="position" type="hidden" value="0">
        <input type="button" name="submit" value="上記の内容で送信する" class="text-center " id="button">
      </form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
          window.onload = function () {
              $(window).scrollTop(<?php echo $position; ?>);}
              
              $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
                
                var position = $(window).scrollTop();
                $("input:hidden[name=position]").val(position);
  
                ("#form").submit();
              }); 
            });  
</script>
```

Comment: ブラウザでJavascriptのエラーは発生していないですか？F12で確認できると思います。

Comment: JSのエラーはありませんでした。

Comment: ("#form").submit(); て　$("#form").submit(); では？

Comment: 回答される方へ　https://teratail.com/questions/294470